# Bean updated with value from f:param through homonymous f:viewParam binding

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra, viewparams

With this code :

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="aParameter" value="#{myBean.aParameter}" /> 
</f:metadata>

...

<h:commandLink  value="commandLink" action="#{myBean.navigate()}">
   <f:param name="aParameter" value="TEST" />
</h:commandLink>
```

When I submit with the commandLink, myBean.aParameter **is updated by the viewParam (seen in debug) with the value** from the f:param in the UPDATE_MODEL phase.

Is this normal ?

And yes, I know the viewParam and the param have the same name, I have no choice on that.

I use Mojarra 2.1.27

Comment: Yes it's normal. What is the concern here exactly?

Comment: Well, the viewParam binds myBean.aParameter with a value from the url, the f:param is a child of the commandLink and I've not found a clue that the both of them could be linked. Can you point me to a reference that says so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I pieced together the reasons why it's *normal* :

- [commandLink's f:param's are submitted](https://community.jboss.org/thread/15890) to the server (I didn't think so) and are part of the requestParametersMap
- [f:viewParam's do the entire JSF livecycle](http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/), even on postbacks
- f:viewParam's then update their values, with what's in the requestParametersMap
- if the requestParametersMap happens to have keys corresponding to viewParam's names, the viewParam does its thing (uses the value to update the model)

So... *that's* normal. I'll modify this behaviour with stateless viewParam's (like [OmniFaces' o:viewParam](http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2012/03/stateless-view-parameter.html)) : no update on postbacks, no more problems !

---

But I don't know why my problem appeared with mojarra 2.1.27 whereas everything seemed fine with 2.1.25. Well...